# How can using JS to print a Byte array to local machine printer?

Tags: pdf, printing, client

i have pdf's content in byte Array. I want a client way to print this pdf to local printer using js.
It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$http({
    url: yourUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/pdf'
    },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var pdfFile = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'application/pdf'
    });
    var pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfFile);
    var printwWindow = $window.open(pdfUrl);
    printwWindow.print();
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('Sorry, something went wrong')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to open it in Browser window by a Blob first and call print function
i have not tested this code but hopfully it will work

```
var byteArray = yourDocumentBytes;
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
// This will check if the browser is IE
if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
{ 
 var blob = new Blob(byteArray, { type: 'application/pdf' });
 window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, documentName);
} else // If another browser
{ 
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + encodeURIComponent(getBase64(byteArray)));
  element.setAttribute('download', documentName);
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
// and call print function like this
window.print()
```